# How to click "Download Chrome" button from Windows Server in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm unable to download the Google Chrome installer when I'm in Internet Explorer for Windows Server 2012 R2.  I normally set the allowed sites under security, but that doesn't work.  What is preventing me from clicking the "Download Chrome" button?

https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/#

Comment: The answer is `Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration`. if you want to see what it does, open IE and click the link "Effects of Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration" to see the list of config settings. To install, do it the easy way, and just download the offline installer on another box and copy over to the server. Its just plain easier than configing IE to allow the download and install. if you really want to config IE though, paste this url into IE to view instructions on how to do so: res://iesetup.dll/IESecHelp.htm#turnoff

Comment: Frank - I would move that to the answer field if I were you.

Comment: I agree with Richie.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Windows servers ship IE with a locked down configuration that they reffer to as `Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration`. This configuration consists of a set of Zone settings, and additional Advanced settings as well. In their default state, these browsers will display a message about the configuration.

[image]

To see the details of the IE ESC, click the link with the text `Effects of Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration` to see the specific settings.

In prior versions you could simply give the Internet Zone the right to download Files, but that no longer works as well as it had, and Chrome web-based installation also requires scripts and local installer execution, so it in particular is difficult.

If you are just going to use another browser anyway (either to avoid IE, or to get around the configuration), you can consider just disabling IE ESC. To do so, review the help for your specific version of IE, by entering this url: `res://iesetup.dll/IESecHelp.htm#turnoff`.

For Windows Server 2012 and 2012 R2, the instructions are as follows:

> Keeping the Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration enabled
>   on your servers is recommended to help ensure that your servers are
>   not inadvertently exposed to malware or other browser-based attacks.
>   However, in some environments you might wish to turn off the Internet
>   Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration protections to enable easier
>   browsing for administrators or standard users.
>
> To turn off Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration
>
> 1. Close any Internet Explorer browser windows that you might have open.
> 2. Open Server Manager
> 3. If your server is running Windows Server® 2008 R2, in the Security
>      Information section of Server Summary, click Configure IE ESC to open
>      the Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration dialog.
>
>    If your server is running Windows Server® 2012, click Configure this
>      local server to open the Local Server configuration page. Then, in the
>      Properties area, next to IE Enhanced Security Configuration, click On
>      to open the Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration dialog.
> 4. To allow members of the local Administrators group to use Internet
>      Explorer in its default client configuration, under Administrators
>      click Off.
>
>    To allow members of all other groups to use Internet Explorer in its
>      default client configuration, under Users click Off.
>
>    Note   Once the Internet Explorer Enhanced Configuration is turned off
>      for one set of users, Server Manager will display Off next to Internet
>      Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration.
> 5. Click OK to apply your changes

Comment: For one reason or another on server 2016 turning this off doesn't stop pages from being blocked because of it.... are other actions needed?

Comment: For Windows Server 2019, just enable [File Downloads for the Internet Zone](https://improveandrepeat.com/2018/03/internet-explorer-on-windows-server-enable-file-downloads/) in the IE Security Settings.

Answer (score 29):

I use powershell for install Chrome in Windows Server 2012 R2/2016/2019:

```
$LocalTempDir = $env:TEMP; $ChromeInstaller = "ChromeInstaller.exe"; (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://dl.google.com/chrome/install/375.126/chrome_installer.exe', "$LocalTempDir\$ChromeInstaller"); & "$LocalTempDir\$ChromeInstaller" /silent /install; $Process2Monitor =  "ChromeInstaller"; Do { $ProcessesFound = Get-Process | ?{$Process2Monitor -contains $_.Name} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name; If ($ProcessesFound) { "Still running: $($ProcessesFound -join ', ')" | Write-Host; Start-Sleep -Seconds 2 } else { rm "$LocalTempDir\$ChromeInstaller" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose } } Until (!$ProcessesFound)
```

Of course I Know is not recommendable, but sometimes you need a browser for get some files.

If you want autoinstall Chrome in your EC2 Windows, put this in your userdata:

```
<powershell>
$LocalTempDir = $env:TEMP; $ChromeInstaller = "ChromeInstaller.exe"; (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://dl.google.com/chrome/install/375.126/chrome_installer.exe', "$LocalTempDir\$ChromeInstaller"); & "$LocalTempDir\$ChromeInstaller" /silent /install; $Process2Monitor =  "ChromeInstaller"; Do { $ProcessesFound = Get-Process | ?{$Process2Monitor -contains $_.Name} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name; If ($ProcessesFound) { "Still running: $($ProcessesFound -join ', ')" | Write-Host; Start-Sleep -Seconds 2 } else { rm "$LocalTempDir\$ChromeInstaller" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose } } Until (!$ProcessesFound)
</powershell>
```

Comment: ```wget http://dl.google.com/chrome/install/375.126/chrome_installer.exe -outfile chrome.exe```

Comment: @jorgem many thanks you saved my day!

Answer (score 10):

For me, I did the following and I was able to download chrome on windows server 2019.

1. Turn off Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration. Click [here](https://medium.com/tensult/disable-internet-explorer-enhanced-security-configuration-in-windows-server-2019-a9cf5528be65) to see how.
2. Enable File download. Click [here](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/enable-file-downloads-in-internet-explorer/) to see how
3. Enable Active Scripting (JavaScript). Click [here](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/how-to-enable-javascript/internet-explorer) to see how

The download chrome button worked fine after I did all that.

Comment: actually just the first bullet is enough, worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Just Add https://www.google.com to your Trusted Sites and turn then go into Custom Level on the Security and disable Pop-up Blocking.

Answer (score 1):

Instructions for mac users ;)

1. Open "Server Manager" (search with magnifying glass in bottom left)
2. Click "Local Server"
3. The IE settings can be disabled with this link:

[image: location of the IE settings link]

Comment: Isn't this Windows Server, rather than Mac?

Comment: @MacGyver, yes. I was jokingly trying to say: "here is a simple answer for people not familiar with Windows" ;)

Comment: Gotcha chief...

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Server 2019, open IE, go to IE options ---> Security ----> Custom -----> select Medium-High (default) from drop down.

Answer (score 0):

- Open the Windows Start menu, and then open Server Manager.

Follow the instructions for the Windows Server version that your EC2 Windows instance is running:

- Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2016, or Windows Server 2019:
  Choose Local Server from the left navigation pane.
- For IE Enhanced Security Configuration, choose On.
- Windows Server 2008 R2: Choose Server Manager from the navigation
  pane. In the Server Summary - Security Information section, choose
  Configure IE ESC.
- For Administrators, select Off.
- For Users, select Off.
- Choose OK.
- Close Server Manager.